# pacman mirrors aren't working at all

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman, mirror

Whenever im trying to -Sy or install a new package, installation fails with error 'failed retrieving file *package name*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I fixed it with:

```
modprobe r8169
```

Comment: What you changed, where. Please elaborate!